# Migrating SAS Reports Into SSRS

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssis, sas, ssrs-2012

I am very new to working with SAS, have not worked with it before. My current workplace is asking me to migrate reports over from SAS and rework them using SSIS/SSRS. I'm not sure how would be the best way to go about this or where even to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I do not believe there is any way to take SAS code and turn it into SSRS reports.  You will have to look at the SAS output and recreate it in SSRS.

Comment: Thank you @DomPazz! Appreciate the reply. So (just speaking out loud so I understand)...easiest way to do this is to replicate data from SAS onto Excel sheet if possible...do SSIS/ETL to transfer data into SQL Server and then recreate from there, right?

Comment: Basically, yes.  I would take the source data from where ever SAS gets it (it might already be in a database) and get that into the Microsoft environment. From there recreate the report in SSRS.

Comment: SSRS *can* connect to non SQL Server data sources, so that step may not even be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to look at the data sources and the report outputs and figure out what is required to manually recreate the reports from scratch in SQL and SSRS.  There is no conversion tool available.